# SAP Consumer Proxy + Error in WSDL Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl, abap

For my bachelor thesis, I try since few days to solve my problem of creating a Consumer Proxy in ABAP.

I want to implement an asp.Net Webservice. This aps.Net WS get some test data from an SQL Server and transfer it to SAP.

When I try to create a Consumer Proxy, I get this error message:

> Incorrect value: Unknown namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema 
> Exception of class CX_SLIB 
> Error location: line 3 column 3 in C:\Users...\Desktop\KonWebService.wsdl Path to error location: definitions/types

The WSDL can be received under http://62.171.132.65/KonQuery/KonWebService.asmx?WSDL, here is the part of the WSDL concerning the types:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
      xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
      xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
      xmlns:tns="http:/www.w3.org/"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
      xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
      xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      targetNamespace="http:/www.w3.org/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/www.w3.org/">
      <s:element name="GetLatestKonData">
        <s:complexType/>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetLatestKonDataResponse">
        <s:complexType/>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetLatestKonDataSoapIn">
...
```

I am quite a beginner in coding and Web Service, and currently I do not know how to solve the error. There are many solutions on the internet, but none of them could really help me.

Can anyone here help me? Thank you.

Here is my c#/asp.net code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace QueryApp
{
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Wenn der Aufruf dieses Webdiensts aus einem Skript zulässig sein soll, heben Sie mithilfe von ASP.NET AJAX die Kommentarmarkierung für die folgende Zeile auf. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class KonWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {           
        [WebMethod(Description = "Get all Data from KonTable")]
        public DataSet GetLatestKonData()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string Query = "SELECT * FROM KonTable";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                DataTable konTable = new DataTable("KonsolidationData");

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    konTable.Load(reader);
                    konTable.AcceptChanges();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.Tables.Add(konTable);
                    ds.AcceptChanges();
                    return ds;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For sure, the error is within the Types part (XSD). Not everything is supported by SAP, in that case SAP indicates to edit the XSD so that SAP can work with it ([note 944029 - XML schema supported by ABAP proxy generation](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/944029)). I see that the XSD defines recursive elements, it's not supported by SAP, you should define them as `xs:any` elements, and in the proxy you should map it to an ABAP `XSDANY` element.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to adjust it to xs:any.  I can´t read the SAP note. I dont have an S-User cause i have access only to a trainings system.

Comment: I have edited your question as per Stack Overflow rules to include the message as text instead of image and to include the concerned part of the WSDL **inside** the question instead of an external source, but I realize it's too late as you already changed your WSDL, so maybe it makes the question obsolete now. Please verify.